# Firefox redirects me when using https exception

Tags: c++, firefox, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm testing a local HTTPS (in fact SSL) server with a fake test certificate and after adding an exception in Firefox 33.0 - Ubuntu (I can see the certificate **is** the test certificate I've created), every time I try to *open* the test url on my computer on port *4431*, what happens is that Firefox redirects me to another url (http://www.kataweb.it).

I am completely clueless at this point, because from the logs of my application I can see Firefox forcefully closing the TCP/IP connection to localhost and then doing what it wants, **even if I've got the right certificate exception**.

Of course, other browsers such as Chromium, do behave as expected (those work just fine, they just display the strike-through *https* symbol).

What am I doing wrong? Or is Firefox wrong?
The local test server is written in C++ using openssl (Ubuntu 14.04 x64).

Cheers,

Comment: A bit more info: tried with IE8 and Firefox 33.1 from a virtual WinXP machine, Firefox 31.0 from a virtual Ubuntu 14.04 x64, looks like those are working just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently installing version 34.0 on Ubuntu fixed this problem.
At this point not sure if the cause was a poorly installed plug-in or not...